# Handling empty strings in C# ?? operator

Tags: c#

I am using the following code:

```
string x = str1 ?? str2 ?? str3 ??  "No string";
```

However what if any of these strings (str1, str2, str3) is String.Empty which is !=null?

How do I handle this situation?

Answer (score 7):

You can't with `??`. You could do something like this, using Linq:

```
string x = new[]{ str1, str2, str3, "No string" }.First(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

Comment: You wally - your condition `x != null` just replicates the original solution without solving the problem :-)

Comment: @Dan: Damn, thought no one saw that ;)

Comment: Possibly neat addition: if this is in a helper method declared with a param array (`GetNonEmpty(params string[] args)`) then you can skip the array and just call `GetNonEmpty(str1, str2, "No string")`

Comment: @Dan: Yeah, I can never figure out where I should put methods like this though. `Util` classes just seem gross.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to find a way to make it an extension method, but that doesn't feel right either...

Answer (score 2):

i would write a helper method:

```
    public static string Coalesce(string defaultValue, params string[] values) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultValue))
            throw new ArgumentException("defaultValue");

        foreach (var value in values) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return value;
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
```

usage:

```
var data = StringHelpers.Coalesce("No text", s1, s2, s3, s4);
```

This is not particularly useful, but you can even create an extension method (appending "this" in front of first parameter), maybe change to a more "fluent" name, and write something like:

```
var data = "No Text".IfEmptyOrNull(s1, s2, s3);
```

Comment: This is a pretty awkward usage pattern, no? I should clarify - the extension method is an awkward usage pattern.

Comment: Yes, it looks like ruby with "1.minutes_from_now" expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx).

E.g.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(null)            => true
String.IsNullOrEmpty("")              => true
String.IsNullOrEmpty("hello, world!") => false
```